# jquery modal selected option value

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a working modal for form submission confirmation.  I have a bunch of text fields that work fine. in my script, I have these values, and the modal populates perfectly.

```
$("p#firstName").html("First Name:  "+$("input#firstName").val());
$("p#lastName").html("Last Name:    "+$("input#lastName").val());
```

however, I have a select dropdown.  I tried

```
$("p#department").html("Department:    "+$("input#department").val());
```

and the return is a value of undefined.

I know I am missing something, just not sure what.

Comment: if it is a select... it is not an input ! $("select#department").val() + be carefull, it seems your ids are not uniques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, the select is NOT an input.

Change

```
$("p#department").html("Department:    "+$("input#department").val());
```

To

```
$("p#department").html("Department:    "+$("select#department").val());
```

Also, either use classes or change your ID's to be unique. It does NOT matter if the element is different, the ID's MUST be unique across the entire page.

Comment: That was it tyme...how do i +1 you?

Comment: Click the up arrow on the left side of the post :)

Comment: @bart2puck click the check mark to the left of the answer that satisfies your question

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your select field's ID to something like "inDepartment".

ID attributes must be unique, even if they are different types of DOM objects.

Then try:

```
$("p#department").html("Department:    "+$("select#inDepartment").val());
```